# Org-mode export gets weird symbols at the end of each line while exporting to HTML

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I got some source blocks in my `org` document like this one:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython
print("Hola")
#+END_SRC
```

When the org file is exported to `html` (and only to `html`) I got weird symbols at the end of each line:

`print("Hola") `

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What's the coding system for the buffer you're saving?  `C-h C` `nil` to find out.
Also, what line endings are you using.  Are there any extra characters (as far as you can tell) after the closing `)`? Can you open the html file and view in `hexl-mode` to see what characters those  are?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the buffer is `utf-8`. The characters added at the end (in the `html` file) are `&#57344;&#57345;&#57345;` e.g.: `<span style="color: #51afef;">import</span> seaborn <span style="color: #51afef;">as</span> sns&#57344;&#57345;&#57345;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the culprit is the `fci` package. A working solution was posted [here](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-htmlize.el)

For completeness I am copying the code here, but all the credit should go to the author of the gist, @kaushalmodi. Just add this to your `.emacs` file.

```
(use-package htmlize
 :defer t
  :config
  (progn

    ;; It is required to disable `fci-mode' when `htmlize-buffer' is called;
    ;; otherwise the invisible fci characters show up as funky looking
    ;; visible characters in the source code blocks in the html file.
    ;; http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-09/msg00777.html
    (with-eval-after-load 'fill-column-indicator
      (defvar modi/htmlize-initial-fci-state nil
        "Variable to store the state of `fci-mode' when `htmlize-buffer' is called.")

      (defun modi/htmlize-before-hook-fci-disable ()
        (setq modi/htmlize-initial-fci-state fci-mode)
        (when fci-mode
          (fci-mode -1)))

      (defun modi/htmlize-after-hook-fci-enable-maybe ()
        (when modi/htmlize-initial-fci-state
          (fci-mode 1)))

      (add-hook 'htmlize-before-hook #'modi/htmlize-before-hook-fci-disable)
      (add-hook 'htmlize-after-hook #'modi/htmlize-after-hook-fci-enable-maybe))

    ;; `flyspell-mode' also has to be disabled because depending on the
    ;; theme, the squiggly underlines can either show up in the html file
    ;; or cause elisp errors like:
    ;; (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p (nil . 100))
    (with-eval-after-load 'flyspell
      (defvar modi/htmlize-initial-flyspell-state nil
        "Variable to store the state of `flyspell-mode' when `htmlize-buffer' is called.")

      (defun modi/htmlize-before-hook-flyspell-disable ()
        (setq modi/htmlize-initial-flyspell-state flyspell-mode)
        (when flyspell-mode
          (flyspell-mode -1)))

      (defun modi/htmlize-after-hook-flyspell-enable-maybe ()
        (when modi/htmlize-initial-flyspell-state
          (flyspell-mode 1)))

      (add-hook 'htmlize-before-hook #'modi/htmlize-before-hook-flyspell-disable)
(add-hook 'htmlize-after-hook #'modi/htmlize-after-hook-flyspell-enable-maybe))))
```